# Serve different asset paths based on express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a set of routes on express which are brands.
Id like to serve 2 asset directories to each of these brands. 
One `public/static` for all brand routes and then everything thats under `public/brands/brandName`.

Is this possible ? I have something like this which seems to work but only for the first `/brandName` i request.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/brands/:brand', function (req, res) {

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/brands/' + req.params.brand)));

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/static/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 3000!');
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/static')));

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick;

```
app.use('/brands', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/brands/')));
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/static/')));

app.get('/brands/:brand', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/static/index.html');
});
```